Differences between rotations and translations of different camera properties in LiBGDX
I am trying to understand the camera API (applicable to perspective camera ONLY) of LiBGDX.
It really does not make sense that you can call rotate and translate on many different properties of the camera. I would like to know what is the difference between them?
Here is the list of rotate and translate methods that act on the LibGDX camera:

camera.translate() , camera.rotate()
camera.view.translate() , camera.view.rotate()
camera.position.traMul(Matrix4 m) , camera.position.rotate()
camera.direction.traMul(Matrix4 m) , camera.direction.rotate()

To my understanding, the camera.view is the actual Frustrum of the camera what can be seen on the screen! What is the difference of rotating(translating) the camera's direction, as compared to rotation(translation) of the camera's view?
What about I just translate or rotate the camera and NOT the view of the camera OR the direction OR the position of the camera? What effect will that have?
I have read the documentation and its really lacking in helping us understand! Please someone to help demystified these camera concepts!

At the end of the day, all those methods act upon the view matrix. Like many things in life, there are many ways to skin a cat. All those methods skin the same cat.

hahaha good answer! but, very true. They all do the same thing!
